# All my text is within 1 cell instead of multiple cells? Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

As you can see in the screenshot all my data has been crushed into 1 cell it seems when it is supposed to be in separate cells as shown in the original screenshot.

Any idea how to solve this?

Excel sheet

[image]

Original Image

[image]

Comment: How did you load this information in to Excel?

Comment: I downloaded it from some data site and then added a few extra columns, saved it and when I reopened this is how it was formatted

Comment: What format did you save it in? How did you add those columns? What format is it in now?

Comment: Evidently you have imported the file wrongly, or exported it wrongly. We need more information.

Comment: It is saved as a .csv file

Comment: as I said, I downloaded from a website so when it exported it imported everything for me, I didn't edit anything

Comment: I downloaded it as a .csv file

Comment: @harrymc well I remember editing in during class, saving it in excel and sending to my email, downloading from home and it changes.

Comment: What did you change when editing, and how did you import it? Note: Excel can work directly on CSV files.

Comment: I just added an extra column and saved it, downloaded the excel file from my gmail and opened it in the files as I would normally do

Answer (score 0):

Saving as a TAB DELIMITED file (extension `.txt`, not `.csv`) leads to what you show. However, it only does so if a change has been made in the settings of your `Text to Columns "T2C"` functionality.

To whit, the selected cell showing in the Formula Editor with the separations with all other lines (cells, to be more exact) showing the text shoved up against itself, no separations.

Problem with that? Well, you say you saved it as a `.csv` file. So... read on if you like, or stop here thinking it can't possibly be on point.

The `T2C` functionality has two pathways once fired up. One is "Fixed Width" and will never be mentioned again in this answer. All references to `T2C` will be for the "Delimited" pathway.

Select a cell with content and fire up `T2C`. Choose "Delimited" and move forward. You have an opportunity to select, enter, and otherwise influence the delimiter/s used and how it/they are used. If you clear ALL selections so no delimiter is in any way selected, entered, or hinted at, then EXIT the function, then you are ready to open the file.

If you have a Tab Delimited file and prepare the `T2C` functionality as described, when you open the file, it will not be split into columns, but rather be a single column, one cell per line in the file. All content in a cell will be (apparently) continuous with nothing (apparently) separating what should have been in individual columns in the row. If you select a cell, the Formula Editor will show it with gaps where columns should end and begin.

In other words, VERY MUCH like exactly what your pic shows.

*In fact, the tab delimiter is present, but it takes no, or practically no space, so, since it has no character representation (like "a" is the representation for an "a", but there is no tab "character" to show), it seems essentially invisible.*

What does `T2C` have to do with anything? Well, directly importing from a file and pasting from the Clipboard (*NOT from Excel with the Clipboard sort of involved, but from the Clipboard, usually material sourced into it from a non-Excel source*) are the same thing, in the end, to Excel:  imports. There used to be an easily accessible wizard to do your importing with. It is now called a "legacy wizard" and can be found in the Data tab of the Ribbon Menu System if you look for it. That wizard is used for the `T2C` functionality, just entered at the point at which data exists and Excel needs to be told how to display it. So a full import uses the whole wizard, and `T2C` uses a subset of it.

Well, pasting from a non-Excel source is still an import, but Excel enters the wizard's code even later down:  it doesn't even ask you for how it should display it. It simply displays it as if you entered the `T2C` functionality, made choices right then before the paste, and told Excel to get to it. This, by the way, is why some pasting goes very strangely (or "badly"). Something to remember other places and times.

The `T2C` functionality remembers your choices from its last use (yay...) so if, for any reason, you used it and deselected the TAB delimiter (I mention clearing everything, above, for clarity here, but you CAN have other things selected so long as TAB is not, and nothing else that might be selected is in the line's string.), then anything tab delimited that is imported will be imported without splitting into columns.

All looks great (and IS) when you create it and save. It's the opening of it later that triggers the import (i.e.:  conversion to Excel form) situation.

And it all matches beautifully with what you are experiencing except for the statement that you saved as a `.csv`.

If saved as a `.csv`, the commas are actually placed in the line's string, same as I mentioned for the "invisible" tab characters. So you'd SEE them on the screen AND in the Formula Editor. What you are showing in the first pic is TAB separation, not comma separation, so either it was not saved as a `.csv` or it was saved as some "CSV" in which the delimiter was a TAB, not a comma, so... "TSV", so to speak.

In any case, no need to harp on that. Just open the file and Select all the cells with content. Enter the `T2C` process and follow the "Delimited" path. Make sure TAB (first one) has a check next to it. No checks for anything else. Click `FINISH` to do the `T2C` and see if you suddenly have all the columns you should. If so, you know what happened and what to look for in the future. If not, then... something else happened, eh?

Side note:  After I use `T2C`, I always re-enter it going to the delimiters and restoring it to "TAB selected (checked), nothing else selected", then immediately exit it. That way I don't get the occasional odd surprise.